# Spell check in Slide Master View in PowerPoint 2016

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In Office 365 - PowerPoint 2016, spell check is checking the Slide Master View as well as the presentation slides - is there any way to stop Spell check automatically activating Slide Master View and checking the Slide Master layouts?  This is frustrating as I don't want my users going into the Slide Master View.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to make sure that everything is spelled correctly on the master/layouts in the first place, which I realize may not even be possible (if your users are working in different languages and/or you have to use technical terms or other words that are not in the user's spelling dictionary.)